# How to add and remove div's (input)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twig

I'm trying to make a page where you can fill in the categories used for news on my website. And ofcourse on this page you should be able to add and remove categories. Now the problem is.... is don't know how. I have no JS only made with html what it should look like.

Output : http://prntscr.com/59x898 http://prntscr.com/59x8cx

My HTML :

```
    <div class="titles">
        <h4>Edit categories</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="portfolioContainer">
        <form class="form-theme col-md-12" action="#">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">

                    <!-- This is where the divs should be -->

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 addRemoveB">
                    <input type="button" onclick="" value="+" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 addRemoveB">
                    <input type="button" onclick="" value="-" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
    <!-- End Recent Post -->
```

This is what a div looks like :

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Categorie 1 </label>
    <input type="cat"  required="required" maxlength="30" class="form-control" name="cat" id="cat">
</div>
```

My css.... well lets just say its everywhere spread over those 1000 lines or so...

Also is it possible to make it so that the label, id and name of the input changes when you add a new one? For example, cat-1 cat-2 so on.

Thanks a bunch !! <3

Comment: i dont have any js/ php yet... i prefer php or js if thats what you mean and for adding and removing i want to use the 2 buttons with the '+' '-' in it, those buttons dont have any effect yet

Comment: So basically you want someone else to do it for you?

Comment: Help me on my way.. dont know where to start and cant find a proper tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I am using jquery add div and delete it. if you want more ask me your use case.I change my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 0;
  $("#plus").click(function() {
    i++;
    $("body").append("<div id='cat" + i + "'>hi " + i +"</div>")
  });
  $("#minus").click(function() {
    $("#cat" + i).remove();
    i--;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6" id="div1">
  <label>Categorie 1</label>
  <input type="text" required="required" maxlength="30" class="form-control" name="cat" id="cat">
</div>
<input type="button" value="Plus" id="plus" />
<input type="button" value="Minuss" id="minus" />
```

Comment: Like you have it it just appends the same div on click and has the same id name, and multiple elements with same id is not allowed.

Comment: its works for me. anyway I recheck and fix that bug.

Comment: Yeah thanks man it works i only have one problem now... when i try to put the Categorie in the append it doesnt work, i thinks it is a problem with the " and '

Comment: I fixed that but now the panel-box doesnt extend when i add one... so the buttons dissapear beneath the panel-box http://prntscr.com/59xse7

Comment: Fixed... and yet another problem rises upon me.... http://prntscr.com/59xu3e i have changed portfolioContainer to container... And also the label doesnt remove